# Visual studio code runs NPM outside integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I run NPM command on VSCode integrated terminal (cmd.exe or powershell) it spawns a new window, of NPM and outputs IO to that window.

It wasn't always like that.
I remember being able to have its output streamed to VSCode's integrated terminal.

[image: vscode integrated terminal fails to output IO within vscode]

Comment: If you run `npm` from `powershell` or `cmd.exe` itself, does it also start up a new terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

future searchers: `Run as Administrator` is your friend.

[image]

Comment: What about those of us who cannot run as administrator? My developer machines are locked down due to company policy. Running as Admin is NOT a thing in most corporations.