# why are vscode npm commands opening in new cmd/node window

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, windows-10, nvm

my question is why are vscode npm commands opening in new cmd/node window instead of inside vscode terminal. Since installing [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to make updating node easier I found that when I run any command in vs code terminal window like:

```
npm run start
npm run build
npm test
```

They all open up a new cmd window instead of running within the vs terminal like I'm sure they use to!? It's super annoying as the cmd windows get in the way, especially when running a js watch script. They also periodically pop up when I'm working is vs code for some random reason. I uninstall node and vscode and removed all dependencies and started from scratch but still had the same behaviour

[image: Run Command]
[image: Randow windows appearing periodically]
[image: Watch window getting in the way]
[image: Test command]

I couldn't find an answer on SO or google, Does anyone know why this is or more importantly how to ensure the commands run in vscode terminal stay there, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh wow !...I really am a muppet, it turns out the fix was as simple as this :

[Visual studio code runs NPM outside integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444951/visual-studio-code-runs-npm-outside-integrated-terminal)

*sigh* I really wish id known that before wasting hours of my life trying to fix it